# Where is the source code for System.String for .Net Core?

Tags: .net, .net-core

The `String` class for older versions should be at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs. Where can I find the class for .Net Core. And also where can I find `StringNative.cpp` which is a base for this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All the .NET Core source code is on Github, broken into [corefx](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx) for the BCL beyond the bits that the CLR really depends on and [coreclr](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr) for the CLR and the core parts of the BCL (like string).

[`stringnative.cpp`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/classlibnative/bcltype/stringnative.cpp) is the native part of the CoreCLR string implementation, and [`String.cs`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/String.cs) contains the managed code.

Comment: I looked through stringnative.cpp and String.cs and couldn't find "operator +" in it. Where is it defined?

Comment: @Kate: There *is* no + operator in the type itself - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-8.0 for example. In C# at least, the + operator is defined in the language... see https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/draft-v7/standard/expressions.md#12105-addition-operator (I *suspect* it has to be in the language for constant folding purposes, but I wouldn't like to swear to it.)

Comment: It is fun to look at `String.Manipulation.cs` in https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/e138ff137f4d727448ed171c6015905fb2d4781a/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/String.Manipulation.cs